# How to query in cosmosDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I write the following query in my cosmosDb no Sql database: select * from c join t in c.model where t.modelName = "test" and i don't get any result ? why ?

[image]

Comment: FYI it's really important to include properly-formatted text (code/data/errors/etc) and not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 1):

Join is used for arrays. Nested properties are accessed via a dot accessor.

Try...

```
select * from c where c.model.modelName = "test"
```

See [Accessing nested properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/working-with-json#nested-properties) for more information.